# Types of Train test split

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

Can anyone explain me these 2 different types of train test split. I know the first one. The second one I saw it on someones code.

```
train_text, temp_text, train_labels, temp_labels = train_test_split(df['text'], df['spam'], 
                                                                random_state=42, 
                                                                test_size=0.3, 
                                                                stratify=df['spam'])
```

```
df_train, df_valid = model_selection.train_test_split(
                                                   text, test_size=0.1, 
                                                    random_state=42, stratify=data.spam.values)
```

In the second example why did the person take only 2 variables instead of 4

Answer (score 1):

> why did the person take only 2 variables instead of 4

The reason is that the [`train_test_split`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) takes two types of parameters - `*arrays` and `**options` - and:

- In the first example the `*arrays` are `df['text'], df['spam']`. The rest of the arguments (the `**options`) are not relevant to the question. So, the function receives two arrays - `df['text']` and `df['spam']` and it produces train&test splits for each of the two arrays, therefore it has 4 results.
- In the second example, only one array is provided - `text` so the function returns only two results - the train and the test splits of the `text`.

The documentation of the function states that it returns:

> splitting: list, length=2 * len(arrays)
> List containing train-test split of inputs.

Comment: what would be the example would had been

 df_train, df_valid = model_selection.train_test_split(
                                                   df, test_size=0.1, 
                                                    random_state=42, stratify=data.spam.values)

It would had fragmented the entire data frame?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). If you use `stratify` the data will be split using the value of stratify as class labels in a stratified fashion. Which helps in class distribution.

If so since in both the first and second example `stratify` is not `None`, the data will be stratified.